# Wordpress setup one database with two different website?

Tags: themes, options

Hello Friends I want to setup two website `first.com` and `second.in` that are different domain and server.

I want to a same data base in both site with the same content.

```
means we enter new posts in first.com then after that posts show in both sites.
```

i want to share every thing in both site like posts,page,comment,etc....

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty hard to tell since you didnt give a lot of information, but First, make sure both sites connect to the same database. Then add those lines in the wp-config.php of each sites to make sure your sites are going to get the right  value of wp_home and wp_siteurl depending on which server your are connected to :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('WP_SITEURL','http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

Comment: that is not enough, you might need also to handle urls which are part of the content.